# How to connect a running container(tomcat) on amazon ec2 to RDS postgres

Tags: postgresql, tomcat, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-vpc

In aws, I have an amazon linux instance running with docker installed and my app running as a container. It's running in tomcat. However I need to connect it to my database.
I have made this work with a postgres container earlier doing this:

```
    docker run --link <dbcontainername>:db -P -d tomcat-image
```

But to have the database more reliable it is wanted to use amazon RDS instead.
I have created a VPC with two subnets which both the instance and the RDS uses
And they are also both in the same Security Group.
I am able to access the tomcat fine through the public ip, but it throws errors because it isn't connected to the db.

Networking is not my strong suit, so there might be something there I am missing, but I find it hard to find any text describing this process without mentioning Elastic bean stalk.(It is my impression that it should be possible to do everything EBS does, manually)

There's a similar question asked here about 8 months ago, but he didn't get any responses so I'm trying again.

Comment: Do you have a postgreSQL connection string that works to connect to your RDS instance from your EC2 instance (outside of Tomcat)?

Comment: I'm not sure what a connection string is, or how to use it.

Comment: Can you `ssh` into the EC2 instance and run the `postgresql` command-line utility to connect to your RDS instance? If so, what are the connection options required? Hostname/IP? Port number? Database/tablespace name? That's all you need in order to configure a "connection string" for a JDBC datasource.

Comment: When sshed into the EC2 instance, I am unable to connect with the RDS in any way. I have tried pinging it at it's endoint as well as "psql -h endpoint" But there's no response. Like I said though it might be a problem with my networking, but I have a custom tcp rule with the RDS' port open

Comment: Agreed: you need to figure-out your networking before you can try to configure Tomcat to use this RDS instance. Note that your RDS instance might not respond to a ping... it might only support connections to the postgresql service.